# Etiquette for replying in comments (e.g. "Thanks, I've updated my question." or "Good point; I've edited my question.")

Tags: discussion

I take it for granted that comments that solely contain "thanks", etc. are inappropriate (such is the purpose of upvoting). However, are responses such as "Good point; I've edited my question." considered appropriate?

Comment: Comments like that are for the purposes of notifying another user that a post has been edited, presumably in response to a request for clarification or concern, so they seem perfectly reasonable to me (though they can be deleted after the other person has seen the change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to comment when you have ask for clarification (main purpose of comments) or expect some action in response to the comment.

Additionally keep in mind that there is limited number of notifications visible/highlighted  and if you just ping people with "thanks" you can effectively hide notifications from other users who actually needed response from that user.

In that light:

- "Good point; I've edited my question." - not useful comment as "edit" is an expected action to clarification comments. Adding one only creates extra work to flag it and then time to delete. While it implicitly asks for "please look at my post again" I think it's better to explicitly as for review. Please be respectful of other's time so - if you confident enough the edit (or whatever expected action) matches commenters expectation - up vote comment but don't ping the person unnecessary.
- "@XXXXX - Good point; I've edited my question. Please check if *Foobar description* matches what you expect to see" on other hand is useful variation as you are requesting a particular action.
- "thanks" - never useful as comment. Flag as "no longer necessary" if it is not yours, don't add your own. As good alternative while editing (especially for answers) consider if attributing changes to a particular commenter is needed. If commenter provided a valuable information that is not generally known (not on the first page of the doc you've linked to) than attributing change with *"(as suggested by {link to user profile})"* is both "thanks" and satisfying licensing of the content.